# Node/Express + MySQL: Inserts not displaying instantly

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, select, insert

I have a form called #add_blog_post with the action "/mysql_test/add_blog_post" and method of "POST"

Jade markup:

```
form#add_blog_post(action="/mysql_test/add_blog_post" method="POST")
```

This form executes the following code in my `app.js`:

```
app.post('/mysql_test/add_blog_post', function(req, res) {
  var author = req.body.author;
  var date = req.body.date;
  var title = req.body.title;
  var body = req.body.body;
  var blog_insert_query = "insert into 332project.blog(author,date,title,body) values(";
  blog_insert_query += ("'"+author+"'"+","); blog_insert_query += ("'"+date+"'"+","); blog_insert_query += ("'"+title+"'"+","); blog_insert_query += ("'"+body+"'"+")");

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS
  });
  connection.connect(function(err) { /*error?*/ });

  var result;
  var query = connection.query(blog_insert_query, function(err, result) {
    res.redirect('/mysql_test');
  });
});
```

The blog post insert works just fine but the website takes a while for the insert to be displayed from the select statement on /mysql_test.

Here is my route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db_calls = require('../db.js');

var connection = db_calls.connect();
connection.connect(function(err) { /*error?*/ });

var result;
var query = connection.query("select * from 332project.blog order by id desc", function(err, rows, fields) {
    connection.end();
    if (!err) {
        result = rows;
    }
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('mysql_test', { 
        result: result
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

What gives? It almost seems like a caching issue. I'd really like for my create/update operations to be instantly visible in my application.

Source code: https://github.com/harwoodjp/learning-express

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that you're not calling `connection.end()` [per the docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction).

Comment: tried throwing in a `connection.end()` at the end of the query before redirecting and still the same behavior.

Comment: Within the `query` callback, or after it?

Comment: I tried it both within the callback and after it. Nothin' :/